# How to display data from sql server in apache drill using c#

Tags: c#, .net, apache-drill

Hello everyone,
              I want to use Apache Drill in my C# programming.
I want to display data from sql server in a webpage using apache drill. please help me out.

Comment: too broad
There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @mybirthname: Actually I am new in apache drill, i don,t know how to connect with sql server. would you please give me some demo showing a simple page having  displaying data  from sql server using apache drill in c# please.. any simple example... so that i will get some idea from that about apche drill.

Comment: I guess you must first configure ODBC data source and then use this ODBC Connection from .NET https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-odbc-on-windows/

Comment: I think you should ask this question over **user group** of drill( https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/)

Comment: @mybirthname: hello I have configure ODBC data source, would you please tell me how to use odbc connection in simple .net project.

Comment: How can i write this java code in c#: ---     Class.forName("org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:drill:zk=
node3.mynode.com:2181/drill/my_cluster_com-drillbits");
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from cp.`employee`");
while(rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}

Answer (score 3):

Rather than going straight to apache drill using the jdbc driver you could leverage the REST API over http. You can read more on it [here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/rest-api/).

In fact I have actually got this working using .NET, in this case F# as opposed to C# but it shouldn't matter.

Please see the example code snippet below:

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"

open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.HttpRequestHeaders

let asyncExecute (queryString : string) =  

    printfn "Executing query string:\n%s..." queryString

    Http.AsyncRequestString(
        url = "http://10.xx.xx.xx:8047/query.json",
        httpMethod = "Post",
        headers = [ ContentType HttpContentTypes.Json ],
        body = TextRequest (sprintf """{"queryType":"SQL", "query": "%s"}""" (queryString.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "")))
    )

let sql =
    @"Select DateKey,
            `Date` 
         From dwTest.SalesDriversDatamart.dwh.DimDate 
         Where Cast(`Date` As Date) = Cast('1990-01-02' As Date)"    

let jsonResult = 
    asyncExecute sql
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```